# PostgreSQL COPY command shifting CSV values into wrong column

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am running the following query in PostgreSQL 10.1:

```
COPY addressbase FROM 'C:/Temp/ab_postgres/addressbase.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

It is returning the error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "SY22 6XP"
CONTEXT: COPY addressbase, line 2, column y_coordinate: "SY22 6XP"
SQL state: 22P02
```

I fully understand that it's stating I can't put text in a numeric field. But my issue is that the value SY22 6XP is not actually in that field at all. So how come when I run this query, it moves the values in the CSV to different columns? See a snapshot of the data below - the value referenced here is in K2, not M2 which is where PostgreSQL is seeing it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the column names to ensure they are in the proper order

```sql
COPY addressbase(UPRN,OS_ADDRESS_TOID,...) 
FROM 'C:/Temp/ab_postgres/addressbase.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

Comment: Okay so that solved it for my test file. Now I'm using a larger file, it doesn't work at all. Regardless of whether or not I specify the column names, the query runs for about 5 mins and adds no lines to the table... I can't work out why as there is no error coming back?

Comment: @JClarkson This is a completely different question (and better suited in other sites such as StackOverflow or DBA StackExchange) with multiple possible reasons (trigger, lack of auto commit etc). But since there is no error and it takes some time to run, the data is inserted (and probably dismissed afterward)

Comment: No worries, thank you. I found that if I split the data into smaller CSVs, that it loaded perfectly, so possibly just too many rows for it to handle (total number of rows is over 30 million!)